# Confused About Deutsche Bahn Train Ticket

Tags: trains, tickets, berlin, deutsche-bahn

This is my first time traveling in Europe and I'm a little confused about my Deutsche Bahn train ticket. Here is what happened:

I bought a train ticket on April 21st from Amsterdam Centraal to Berlin Hbf, which was a direct route. I had an e-mail saying because of the timetable change, my journey is not available. I couldn't cancel and there was no alternative connections. I panicked and I canceled my ticket on Omio with 10 Euro deducted. And I bought another ticket with one transfer (also paying extra money): Amsterdam to Hannover, Hannover to Berlin. Now I know I shouldn't have done that because I could take any train without needing to cancel and buying new tickets.

So, here is my real question. My new ticket is on April 21st at 09:59 am. On the int.bahn website, I selected an alternative connection thinking I would change the time of my ticket. Now it says "I have an alternative itinerary at 11:59am" and I also can see my original ticket saying "Original itinerary" at 09:59 am. My ticket is Super Sparpreis Europa, 2nd Cl, which is a train-specific ticket. I think it means that I cannot change or cancel my ticket. So which train should I take, the one at 09:59 (original) or 11:59 (alternative). I cannot upload the screenshot of the tickets, so I'm writing what I see.

Please check whether your ticket is valid for the alternative you selected.
Super Sparpreis Europa, 2nd Cl.
Single Journey

Your alternative travel itinerary on Sun 21. Apr 2024
11:59-18:16

Original itinerary
09:59-16-16

You should know that I am very scared right now. Because I didn't know the system, I panicked and I messed up. It's all my fault.
I appreciate any suggestion you give and I thank you guys in advance.

To the people that will help me! If you are around Amsterdam or Berlin, I can buy you a cup of coffee

Comment: Sorry this is very confusing to read. Which "website" are you talking about? Where did the "alternative" connection come from? Is that something they offered or something you asked for ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to change the time of my ticket on the int.bahn website by selecting for alternative connection. I now know  that alternative connection is not changing the time of the ticket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...and I also can see my original ticket saying "Original itinerary" at 09:59 am. My ticket is **Super Sparpreis Europa**, 2nd Cl. which is a train-specific ticket. I think it means that I cannot change or cancel my ticket. So which train should I take, **the one at 09:59 (original)** or 11:59 (alternative).

Yes, the *Super Sparpreis Europa* is a train-specific ticket, so you must take the original 09:59 train.

This restriction applies to the first leg of your trip.

For the second leg of your journey it is less restrictive: you can take an earlier train **or if the train arrives late**, a later train.

---

> [Wie war das nochmal mit der Zugbindung?](https://www.bahn.de/service/ueber-uns/inside-bahn/tipps-tricks/zugbindung-sparpreis)
> **Was ist eine Zugbindung?**
> Zugbindung bedeutet, dass Sie nur mit dem Zug zur eingetragenen Uhrzeit auf dem ausgestellten Fahrschein fahren dürfen. Die Zugbindung gilt nur für die Züge des Fernverkehrs und in Verbindung mit einem Sparpreis-Ticket oder einem Sonderticket. Dazu zählen folgende Züge: Intercity-Express (ICE), Intercity (IC), Eurocity (EC), EuroNight (EN) oder D-Zug (D).
>
> > **What is a train restriction?**
> > Train restriction means that you can only travel on the train at the time specified on the ticket issued. The train restriction only applies to long-distance trains and in conjunction with a saver fare ticket or a special ticket. These include the following trains: Intercity-Express (ICE), Intercity (IC), Eurocity (EC), EuroNight (EN) or D-Zug (D).
>
> **Zug verpasst - was nun?**
> Sie haben Ihren Anschlusszug wegen einer vorangegangenen Verspätung Ihres Zuges verpasst? Kein Problem. Nehmen Sie einfach den nächsten Zug zu Ihrem Reiseziel. Die Zugbindung müssen Sie nicht mehr vorher vom Zugpersonal, im DB Reisezentrum oder an der DB Information aufheben lassen.
> Wenn kein Verschulden seitens der Deutschen Bahn vorliegt, erlischt die Gültigkeit Ihres Tickets. Damit Sie trotzdem an Ihr Ziel kommen, müssen Sie sich ein neues Ticket für Ihre Reise kaufen.
>
> > **Missed the train - what now?**
> > You missed your connecting train because your train was delayed? No problem. Simply take the next train to your destination. You no longer need to have the train connection canceled in advance by the train staff, at the DB travel center or at the DB information desk.
> > If Deutsche Bahn is not at fault, your ticket will no longer be valid. In order to still reach your destination, you must buy a new ticket for your journey.
>
> **Mein Umstieg verlief schnell und ich schaffe einen vorherigen Zug – darf ich diesen trotz Zugbindung nehmen?**
> Im DB Navigator oder auf unserer Website werden großzügige Umsteigezeiten angegeben, damit Anschlusszüge zuverlässiger erreicht werden können. Doch Sie sind besonders schnell und der Umstieg lief besser als geplant? Kein Problem! Sollten Sie entgegen der gebuchten Reiseverbindung dennoch auch Anschlüsse mit kürzerer Übergangszeit erreichen, können Sie auch mit zuggebundenen Tickets den früheren Anschlusszug nutzen. Für diese Fälle heben wir die Zugbindung für mehr Flexibilität auf.
>
> > **My transfer was quick and I managed to catch an earlier train - can I take this despite the train connection?**
> > The DB Navigator or our website provide generous transfer times so that connecting trains can be reached more reliably. But you are particularly quick and the transfer went better than planned? No problem! If, contrary to the booked travel connection, you still manage to catch connections with a shorter transfer time, you can also use the earlier connecting train with train-specific tickets. In these cases, we remove the train connection for more flexibility.
>
> **Und wenn sich die Reisepläne ändern?**
> Ab dem Reisetag ist eine Stornierung beim Sparpreis nicht mehr möglich. Davor erstatten wir Ihnen Sparpreis-Tickets abzüglich einer Gebühr von 10 Euro als Gutschein und Sie haben die Möglichkeit, ein neues Ticket  zu buchen. Tickets, die über diese Website oder im DB Navigator gebucht wurden, können innerhalb von 12 Stunden (720 Minuten) nach der Buchung und vor dem 1. Geltungstag kostenlos storniert werden. Sie erhalten den kompletten Zahlungsbetrag zurück. Die Sofortstornierung greift immer für den gesamten Auftrag und umfasst auch die zusätzlich gebuchten Leistungen (Sitzplatzreservierung, Fahrradkarte, City mobil, Fahrkarten-Schutz). Aktionsgutscheine können nicht erstattet werden. Buchungen mit Gutscheinzahlung, bei denen ein Restwertgutschein versendet wurden, können sofort storniert werden.
> Für mehr Flexibilität auf Ihrer Reise empfehlen wir Ihnen das Ticket zum Flexpreis.
>
> > **And if your travel plans change?**
> > Cancellation of saver fares is no longer possible from the day of travel. Before that, we will refund saver fare tickets minus a fee of 10 euros as a voucher and you have the option of booking a new ticket. Tickets booked via this website or in the DB Navigator can be cancelled free of charge within 12 hours (720 minutes) of booking and before the first day of validity. You will receive the full amount paid back. Immediate cancellation always applies to the entire order and also includes the additional services booked (seat reservation, bicycle ticket, City mobil, ticket protection). Promotional vouchers cannot be refunded. Bookings with voucher payment for which a remaining value voucher was sent can be cancelled immediately.
> > For more flexibility on your trip, we recommend the flex price ticket.

Comment: If you take an earlier train, that train is rerouted, and ends up getting you to the next connection later than the train on your ticket which got there on time, what would happen then? You cannot prove that your were delayed because the train on your ticket got there on time, and you are stuck?

Comment: @user253751 For the first leg of your trip, you can only use the train at the time specified on the ticket.

Comment: A trip can connect at more than one intermediate point. If your ticket says for example travelling Frankfurt-Köln-Hannover-Berlin (I'm aware there's a more direct train) you might arrive early at Köln and take an early train to Hannover which might be severely delayed and then you arrive at Hannover too late for your booked Hannover-Berlin train, but you would have been on time if you took your booked train?

Answer (score 1):

As a base rule, you cannot change the time of a "Super Sparpreis" ticket. They are not changeable or refundable.

However, you *can* cancel them within 12 hours of the booking.

**With your current ticket, you must take the train indicated on the ticket.** If you want to take the later one, you need a new ticket for it.

https://int.bahn.de/en/booking-information/exchanges-refunds has the details in English. (Note the difference between "saver" (*Sparpreis*) fares and "super saver" (*Super Sparpreis*) fares, these are distinct categories.)